# Replace multiple characters in SQL?

Tags: sql

how do I show * 
having the following conditions:

1. Student number must not contain the following string: 231
2. The surname must begin with the letter S
3. The course number must not be DEV1 or DEV2

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: Homework? Add sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt. And tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: Have a read on how [select works](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select.php)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 Select * From [TableName] 
 Where Studend_Number not like '%231%' and 
       Student_Surname like '%S' and 
       Course_Number not in ('DEV1','DEV2')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use 3 conditions in WHERE Clauses :

SELECT *
FROM Your_table 
WHERE Studentnumber NOT LIKE '%231%' AND surname LIKE 'S%' AND coursenumber 
NOT IN ('DEV1', 'DEV2')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE student_number <> 231 
   AND surname LIKE 's%' 
   AND coursenumber NOT IN ('DEV1','DEV2')
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  In particular, why is `student_number <> 231` better than `student_number NOT LIKE '%231%`?